# How to encode odd-length byte address for little endian?

Tags: c, function-pointers, endianness, buffer-overflow

I have a buffer and function pointer which is going to be overflowed with an address, what

```
static char buffer[12];
static int (*target_function)(char * str);
```

The overflow itself is not the problem, but I cant seem to put in the right address which is `0x8048338`

As stated in the question, the problem I face now, is how do I encode this address to little endian, or any endianness for that matter ?

Comment: Erm... what? Where is overflow? Which address are you talking about? what does it have to do with endiannes?

Comment: Do you have a function at the address `0x8048338` and want to set the function pointer to it? `static int (*target_function)(char * str) = (int (*)(char * str)) 0x8048338;` should do it, independent from endianess.

Comment: `0x8048338` == `0x08048338`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didnt show the overflow because it is not relevant to the question, my question was how to convert an address so I can pass it as an argument which overflows the buffer into the function pointer. also I dont understand the downvoting, because google didnt give much useful results

Comment: @Eugene Sh., The OP is saying they want to store `0x8048338` in `target_function` by writing beyond the end of `buffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x8048338` as a 32-bit integer in BE byte order is `08 04 83 38`.

`0x8048338` as a 32-bit integer in LE byte order is `38 83 04 08`.

---

Hardcoded:

```
buf[0] = 0x38;
buf[1] = 0x83;
buf[2] = 0x04;
buf[3] = 0x08;
```

From a var:

```
uint32_t n = 0x8048338;

buf[0] = n && 0xFF;  n >>= 8;
buf[1] = n && 0xFF;  n >>= 8;
buf[2] = n && 0xFF;  n >>= 8;
buf[3] = n;
```

With a loop:

```
uint32_t n = 0x8048338;
char* p = buf;
for (int i=4; i--; ) {
   *(p++) = n && 0xFF;
   n >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: Of course, on an LE system, could simply use `memcpy`